# Visual Studio 2005: Unable to connect to visual studio's localhost web server

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2005, cassini

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7 and I was unable to debug a web site in Visual Studio 2005. I got the error: unable to connect to visual studio's localhost web server. I don't know if the upgrade caused it to break, but this was previously working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To resolve this I ran process monitor on devenv.exe to see which calls ended in not SUCCESS. Turns out, my Visual Studio 2005 installation was looking for WebDev.WebServer.exe to be located here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE

Whereas it was missing. I copied it over from here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0

And it seems to work.

Across the internet other answers will tell you it needs to be in the .NET framework folder, but I found that in my case it needed to be in the Visual Studio 8 folder.

Comment: Brilliant worked a treat! The only issue I encountered was (probably due to it being a work environment) I had to use DOS opened as administrator to copy. Nice one @John :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy WebDev.WebServer.EXE from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE" will resolve this.